# socket.io-redis trailing bytes

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io, socket.io-1.0

I am using `socket.io-emitter` to broadcast an event to a set of channels with a for loop:

In the file, I have:

```
var io = require('socket.io-emitter')({
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 6379
});

module.exports = {
  exampleFunction: function(req, res, next) {
    var channels = req.param('channels'),
        data = req.param('data');

    for (var i=0; i<channels.length; i++) {
      io.to(channels[i]).emit('example event', data)
    }
  }
}
```

In `app.js`, I have `socket.io-redis`:

```
io.adapter(socketio_redis({ 
  host: 'localhost', 
  port: 6379,
  pubClient: redis.createClient(6379, '127.0.0.1'),
  subClient: redis.createClient(6379, '127.0.0.1')
}))
```

When I try to run `exampleFunction`, I get the following uncaught error in my console:

```
Error: 348 trailing bytes
    at Object.decode (C:\Users\Website\socket.io-redis\node_modules\msgpack-js\msgpack.js:200:47)
    at Redis.onmessage (C:\Users\Website\socket.io-redis\index.js:93:24)
    at RedisClient.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:106:17)
    at RedisClient.return_reply (C:\Users\Website\node_modules\redis\index.js:672:22)
    at ReplyParser.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Website\node_modules\redis\index.js:309:14)
    at ReplyParser.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at ReplyParser.send_reply (C:\Users\Website\node_modules\redis\lib\parser\javascript.js:300:10)
    at ReplyParser.execute (C:\Users\Website\node_modules\redis\lib\parser\javascript.js:211:22)
    at RedisClient.on_data (C:\Users\Website\node_modules\redis\index.js:534:27)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Website\node_modules\redis\index.js:91:14)
```

I have seen that this is from msgpack. Have any of you encountered this error before? How did you resolve it?

Thank you.

Comment: There is no line 348 of the code. The 348 trailing bytes changes when I pass in different data to the emit function. For example,

io.to(channels[i]).emit('example event', 'hello')

would cause the error to be something more like '95 trailing bytes'

Answer (score 0):

On the main page of [nm.socket.io-redis](https://www.npmjs.org/package/nm.socket.io-redis) it is written:

> Msgpack with giving us an error called "trailing bytes". After reading
>   up we realized that we could just use JSON.stringfy/JSON.parse instead
>   of msgpack.

Which looks like the error you are getting. As it is suggested there, try `JSON.strigfy`

Comment: if I just use JSON.stringify, I get the same error but with less trailing bytes. the nm.socket.io-redis package gives a bunch of additional errors.

Answer (score 0):

Okay,
We found the solution. Refer to:
https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io-redis/issues/17

As you can see, socket.io-emitter requires you set return_buffers to true on your redis client.

Let me know if this works. Otherwise I can dif in the code some more.

Comment: Could you please return a buffer of the solutionary diff? Redis thanks your emitter.

Answer (score 0):

This should answer your question.
https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io-redis/issues/17

Answer (score 0):

This helped me with `Error: -560815898 trailing bytes` error:

1. `npm install msgpack-js-v5`
2. change file `node_modules/socket.io-redis/index.js` at the very top:

   `var msgpack = require('msgpack-js');`

   to

   `var msgpack = require('msgpack-js-v5');`
3. now use code similar to this:

   ```
   var adapter = require('socket.io-redis');
   var pub = redis.createClient(6379, 'localhost');
   var sub = redis.createClient(6379, 'localhost', { return_buffers: true });
   io.adapter(adapter({pubClient: pub, subClient: sub}));
   ```

UPDATE:

In some days I stumbled upon an error `bops.readUInt64BE is not a function`, so eventually I switched `msgpack-js-v5` to `msgpack5` and now it works ok.